# I cannot click the Admin button nested inside the iFrame

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am automating our Web application using Python with Selenium Webdriver.
I log into the application and I want to click the Administration button.
When i run my code it cannot find the Administration button by my Xpath.  I have tried a few different ways.
If i enter //div[7]/div/div in selenium IDE and click Find it highlights the Administration button.  I do not know why it won't find it when i run the code.
I would prefer to use CSS as that is faster than Xpath.
I need some help please.

I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div"}
```

I inspect the HTML element.  The full HTML is as follows:

```
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
<head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
<head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">
<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; border: 0;" tabindex="-1" src="javascript:''">
<html>
</iframe>    
<noscript> <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif;"> Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled in order for this application to display correctly.</div> </noscript>
<script src="spinner.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="ClearCore/ClearCore.nocache.js" type="text/javascript">
<script defer="defer">
<iframe id="ClearCore" src="javascript:''" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</head>
<body>
</html>
</iframe>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 1px; top: 1px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanel" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20ex; width: 10em; height: 10ex; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"> </div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 30px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 16384px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Administration</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 30px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
</div>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 1px; right: 1px; width: 30px; height: 25px;">
<div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: -25px; right: 0px; height: 25px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is as follows:

element.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class BasePageElement(object):

def __set__(self, obj, value):
    driver = obj.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
    driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator).send_keys(value)

def __get__(self, obj, owner):
    driver = obj.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
    element = driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator)
    return element.get_attribute("value")
```

locators.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class MainPageLocators(object):
Submit_button = (By.ID, 'submit')
usernameTxtBox = (By.ID, 'unid')
passwordTxtBox = (By.ID, 'pwid')
submitButton = (By.ID, 'button')
AdministrationButton = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gwt-HTML.firepath-matching-node')
AdministrationButtonXpath = (By.XPATH, '//html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div')
AdministrationButtonCSS = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div')
AdministrationButtonXpath2 = (By.XPATH, 'html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div/text()')
AdministrationButtonXpath3 = (By.XPATH, '//div[7]/div/div')

contentFrame = (By.ID, 'ClearCore')
```

Page.py

```
from element import BasePageElement
from locators import MainPageLocators
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

class SearchTextElement(BasePageElement):


class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver


class LoginPage(BasePage):

search_text_element = SearchTextElement()

def userLogin_valid(self):
    userName_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.usernameTxtBox)
    userName_textbox.clear()
    userName_textbox.send_keys("riaz.ladhani")
    password_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.passwordTxtBox)
    password_textbox.clear()
    password_textbox.send_keys("test123")
    submitButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.submitButton)
    submitButton.click()
    #mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).clear()

def clickAdministration_button(self):

    #administrationButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton)

    content_frame = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.contentFrame)
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(content_frame)
    #self.driver.switch_to.frame(*MainPageLocators.contentFrame)
    #self.driver.Switch_to().Frame(*MainPageLocators.contentFrame)
    #administrationButtonCSS = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButtonCSS)
    #administrationButtonXpath= self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButtonXpath)
    #administrationButtonXpath= self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_CSS_regex)
    #administrationButtonCSS2 = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButtonCSS2)
    adminButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButtonXpath3)
    adminButton.click()
```

LoginPage_TestCase.py

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import page

class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://my-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")

def test_login_valid_user(self):
    login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
    login_page.userLogin_valid()
    login_page.ClickAdministration_button()

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have finally managed to solve my issue. The dev said I had to wait for the page to have fully completed loading. The page was still loading the JavaScript functions when all the elements were displayed on the screen.
I first tried time.sleep(30) then click the button. It worked. Waiting for 30 secs every time is not efficient. I then used WebDriverWait and this is more efficient.

Here is the code i used:

```
WebDriverWait(mydriver, 10).until(lambda d: mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Administration']").click())
```

Answer (score 1):

As the “Administration button” is located under the frame whose id is “**ClearCore**” and it is not in the webpage. That is the reason why the element is unable to locate while executing the code.

So before clicking that button you need to switch to that frame either by using

```
   1.   driver.switch_to_window("windowName")
   2.   driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

Once we are done with working on frames, we will have to come back to the parent frame which can be done using:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Comment: I have tried the following code now. having read other posts where ppl were having trouble with iFrames in Selenium, Python.  My code is still failing to find the button.                                                                                     # Give time for iframe to load 
mydriver.implicitly_wait(10)
# Switch to the iframe: 
mydriver.switch_to_frame(mydriver.find_element_by_id('ClearCore'))
# find the button  
elem = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div')
elem.click()
mydriver.switch_to_default_content()

Comment: On the Seleniumhq documentation site the sytanx for iFrame in Python is driver.switch_to.frame("frameName").  It is not with the underline like driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")  I have tried both ways, it still does not locate the button.  I have been stuck on this for 3 weeks now.

Comment: I know I have switched to the iFrame correctly because if i change the name of the iframe to ClearCoree i get the following error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame: ClearCoree

Comment: I have spoken with the dev, All the elements are outside of the iFrame.  JavaScript  functions are just being loaded in the iFrame tag.  I have tried the following code now and there are no errors.  But still the button is not being clicked.  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

administration = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ""//div[. = 'Administration']""))
)
administration.click()

Comment: I think I may have to use the JavaScript Executor function perhaps to try and locate the Administration button and click on it.

Comment: I Have finally managed to solve my issue. The dev said I had to wait for the page to have fully completed loading. The page was still loading the JavaScript functions when all the elements were displayed on the screen.
I first tried time.sleep(30) then click the button. It worked. Waiting for 30 secs every time is not efficient. I then used WebDriverWait and this is more efficient. Here is the code i used:  WebDriverWait(mydriver, 10).until(lambda d: mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Administration']").click())

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
driver.switch_to_frame("__gwt_historyFrame");
```

before you Administration button click code. This code will take WebDriver into frame, then only WebDriver able to find button inside the frame,
if you want to come out of the frame to navigate outside,
use

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

*"__gwt_historyFrame" this is your frame name

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it.  It does not work.  There are 2 iframes.  <iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" and <iframe id="ClearCore"  Is my xpath correct By.XPATH, '//div[7]/div/div')